# Laravel (Blade) - API + Frontal en el mismo proyecto

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-6, blade

tengo un proyecto con Laravel donde tengo instalado Passport que lo uso para gestionar la authorización y autenticación con la API del proyecto.

Tengo un método login que devuelve el token y luego desde las wep app responsive envio dicho token con cada petición web, esto funciona OK.

Lo que no consigo hacer funcionar, es dentro del mismo proyecto autenticar mediante un formulario que llama otro método

**Método para autenticar**

```
 public function loginweb(Request $request)
    {

        $user = User::where('email',$request->get('email'))
            ->where('password',$request->get('password'))
            ->first();

        if (null !== $user) {
            $request->session()->put('login_email', $request->get('email'));
            $request->session()->put('user_id', $user->id);

            return response()->json($user,200);
        }

        return response()->json('Error',400);
    }
```

**Y el formulario desde donde lo llamo es este**

```
@extends('layouts.user-guest')

@section('content')

    <p>
        LOGIN
    </p>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-12 col-xs-12">
                <form method="post">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @csrf
                        <label for="inputEmail">Email</label>
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" name="inputEmail" id="inputEmail" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="email">
                        <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Escribe tu email.</small>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="inputPassword">Password</label>
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" name="inputPassword" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Contraseña">
                    </div>

                    <button type="submit" id="btnLogin" class="btn btn-primary">LOGIN</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

@endsection

@section('script')
    <script>
        $("#btnLogin").click(function(e) {

            $("#error-list").empty();
            $("#alert-ok").empty();

            var email = $("input[name=inputEmail]").val();
            var password = $("input[name=inputPassword]").val();

            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "{{ route('api.user.dologin') }}",
                data: {
                    "_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}",
                    email : email,
                    password : password
                },

                statusCode: {
                    200: function (response) {
                        window.location = "{{ route('front.user.pages.home') }}"
                    },
                    400: function (response) {
                        alert('error');
                        alert(response);
                    },
                },
                error: function(data) {


                }
            });
        });
    </script>

@endsection
```

En este formulario lo que hago es enviar los parametros introducidos en los inputbox, los envio a esta ruta "api.user.dologin"

Esta ruta he probado a ponerla tanto en el fichero "web.php" como el fichero "api.php"

```
Route::post('dologin', 'AuthController@loginweb')->name('api.user.dologin');
```

Si esta ruta la pongo en el fichero web.php recibo el **error 419 | Page expired**
Si pongo la ruta en el fichero api.php recibo este otro error

```
RuntimeException: Session store not set on request. in file
```

/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Http/Request.php on line 483